# Error when attempting to insert pandas DataFrame into mySQL

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with about `200` columns. I get `sequence item 0: expected str instance, dict found` error when attempting to run:

```
# Insert into SQL
con = engine.connect()
df.to_sql(name="df_raw", con=con, if_exists = 'replace')
con.close()
```

My column datatypes of my table are mixed. i.e `int64`, `float64`, `object` and `dict`. The contents of couple of the columns are stored as `dicts`. Is that an issue?

Traceback:

```
/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/mysqldb.py in do_executemany(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context)
    195 
    196     def do_executemany(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context=None):
--> 197         rowcount = cursor.executemany(statement, parameters)
    198         if context is not None:
    199             context._rowcount = rowcount

/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py in executemany(self, query, args)
    171             q_postfix = m.group(3) or ""
    172             assert q_values[0] == "(" and q_values[-1] == ")"
--> 173             return self._do_execute_many(
    174                 q_prefix,
    175                 q_values,

/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py in _do_execute_many(self, prefix, values, postfix, args, max_stmt_length, encoding)
    194         sql = bytearray(prefix)
    195         args = iter(args)
--> 196         v = values % escape(next(args), conn)
    197         if isinstance(v, str):
    198             v = v.encode(encoding, "surrogateescape")

/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py in _escape_args(self, args, conn)
    107             return tuple(conn.literal(arg) for arg in args)
    108         elif isinstance(args, dict):
--> 109             return {key: conn.literal(val) for (key, val) in args.items()}
    110         else:
    111             # If it's not a dictionary let's try escaping it anyways.

/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py in <dictcomp>(.0)
    107             return tuple(conn.literal(arg) for arg in args)
    108         elif isinstance(args, dict):
--> 109             return {key: conn.literal(val) for (key, val) in args.items()}
    110         else:
    111             # If it's not a dictionary let's try escaping it anyways.

/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py in literal(self, obj)
    515         Non-standard, for internal use; do not use this in your applications.
    516         """
--> 517         return self.escape(obj, self.encoders)
    518 
    519     def escape_string(self, s):

/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py in escape(self, obj, mapping)
    508                 ret = "_binary" + ret
    509             return ret
--> 510         return converters.escape_item(obj, self.charset, mapping=mapping)
    511 
    512     def literal(self, obj):

/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/converters.py in escape_item(val, charset, mapping)
     21 
     22     if encoder in (escape_dict, escape_sequence):
---> 23         val = encoder(val, charset, mapping)
     24     else:
     25         val = encoder(val, mapping)

/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/converters.py in escape_dict(val, charset, mapping)
     30     n = {}
     31     for k, v in val.items():
---> 32         quoted = escape_item(v, charset, mapping)
     33         n[k] = quoted
     34     return n

/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/converters.py in escape_item(val, charset, mapping)
     21 
     22     if encoder in (escape_dict, escape_sequence):
---> 23         val = encoder(val, charset, mapping)
     24     else:
     25         val = encoder(val, mapping)

/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/converters.py in escape_sequence(val, charset, mapping)
     40         quoted = escape_item(item, charset, mapping)
     41         n.append(quoted)
---> 42     return "(" + ",".join(n) + ")"
     43 
     44 

TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, dict found
```

Besides solution suggestions, it would be helpful to know the cause of this issue.

Comment: you can't store a dictionary in a MySQL table column.

Comment: I see, would you mind suggestion a solution on how I transform `columns` that of type `dict` into MySQL compatible `datatype`?

Comment: What are you expecting it to look like in the table? Maybe you could convert it to JSON. Then when you read from the table you can convert it back to a dictionary.

Comment: @Barmar right, I need a programmatic way to find all columns in the df that have contents of type `dict`. Since, the datatype of the column / pandas series itself is `object`.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dtypes.html

Comment: Yep, I can convert and save them in JSON format. And when I query the data, I can convert it to `dict`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243830/discussion-between-kms-and-barmar).